# Python: filter(None, [list of bools]) behavior

Tags: python

EDIT: After reading the suggested link,  I have no idea why this has been marked as a duplicate. Sue me.

Can anyone help me understand why `filter(None, [list of bools])` removes `False` values?

Take the following:

```
low = 25 
high = 35
to_match = [15, 30, 32, 99]
def check(low, high, to_match):
    return [low <= i <= high for i in to_match]
```

`check(low, high, to_match)` returns `[False, True, True, False]`

`filter(None, check(low, high, to_match))` returns `[True, True]`

So I thought, Python must think `False` is `None`! But to my surprise, `False is None` returns `False`!

A) What am I missing?

B) How can I filter only `None` values from `[True, None, False]`?

Comment: `None` is falsy, but the bigger question I'd like to pose to you:  what did you *believe* that `filter(None, [bools])` would give you?

Comment: Why are you getting `None` values? Or is this asking why it is that way?

Comment: @Makoto I assumed `filter(None, [True, False, None])` would return `[True, False]`

Comment: @Tim I'm asking why it's that way. In my actual use case, the function that generates the list of bools may append a `None` in some instances, which was very annoying to type check. I figured I'd just filter them out later.

Comment: I would do `[x for x in check(low, high, to_match) if x in {True, False}]` Works in Python 2 and 3 and filters out other falsey values.

Comment: If you assumed `filter(None, [True, False, None])` would return `[True, False]` and it didn't, maybe the next step would be to Google "python filter none"?

Comment: I cannot understand why PO's question is duplicated. StackOverflow is really unfriendly to newbies.

Comment: I would avoid using filters and use list comprehension as mentioned by @dawg

Answer (score 54):

If you want to filter out `None`, use:

```
filter(lambda x: x is not None, [list of bools])
```

or

```
[x for x in [list of bools] if x is not None]
```

[`filter` takes a function, not a value](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter). `filter(None, ...)` is shorthand for `filter(lambda x: x, ...)` -- it will filter out values that are false-y (emphasis mine):

> `filter(function, iterable)`
>
> Construct a list from those elements of `iterable` for which `function` returns true. `iterable` may be either a sequence, a container which supports iteration, or an iterator. If `iterable` is a string or a tuple, the result also has that type; otherwise it is always a list. **If function is `None`, the identity function is assumed, that is, all elements of `iterable` that are false are removed.**
>
> Note that `filter(function, iterable)` is equivalent to `[item for item in iterable if function(item)]` if function is not `None` and `[item for item in iterable if item]` if function is `None`.

Comment: You should use `is not` instead of `!=` though.

Answer (score 14):

For python3 you can use `None.__ne__` to only remove None, just filtering using None will remove any falsey values like `[], {} 0` etc.. :

```
filter(None.__ne__, check(low, high, to_match))
```

for python2 you would need to add a lambda checking each element `is not None`:

```
filter(lambda x: x is not None,....)
```

If you are using python2 the stick to a list comp:

```
[ele for ele in check(low, high, match) if ele is not None]
```

Any performance gain of using filter will be offset by the lambda calls so it will actually end up slower.

Comment: Using `None.__ne__` issues a warning: `<stdin>:1: DeprecationWarning: NotImplemented should not be used in a boolean context`

Comment: `filter(None.__ne__, L)` [should](https://bugs.python.org/issue35712#msg380603) be written as `list([x for x in L if x is not None])`